# 2D sparse matrix multiplied by 3D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Is there any way to multiply a 2D sparse matrix by a 3D numpy array please?
For example I have this function

```
def myFun(x, p):
    r = 2
    out = x * np.log(p) + r * np.log(1-p)
    return out
```

where x is an array of dimension `3500, 90` and p another array with dimensions `3500, 90, 70`. At the moment both `x` and `p` are dense arrays and I am just broadcasting when I call the function:

```
out = myFun(x[..., None], p)
```

However array `x` is quite sparse, only 7% of its elements are non-zero. On the other side, p doesnt have any zeros, only floats between zero and one.
I am hoping though that with a sparse matrix (from `scipy.sparse` probably) I will see a speed improvement. However, I do not know how to do this operation or if this more efficient please.

I am using python 3.

Many thanks

Comment: What kind of multiplication is the `*` in your example? The way this is written would not work on dense `numpy` arrays due to broadcasting issues.

Comment: I would also recommend to use `numexpr` or `Numba` or any other lib which can use Intel SVML for calculating the logs. This would speed up the function by about a factor 4. Also check if you have enabled multithreading (which seems not be the case by the timings @Paul Panzer got) This will get aprox. another number of cores speedup.

Comment: @max9111 That was very spot on! Many thanks, I used `numexpr` and it did have a big impact. And that was without VML, which I am now trying to make use of. Many thanks again!

Comment: On a Quadcore (Numba+SVML) I got about 0.33s without compilation overhead, while single threaded numpy gives about 4.3s (Testdata from Paul Panzer, also 3 runs)

Comment: @max9111: For Paul's test data I initially had 2.03secs which was cut down to 1.67 after Paul's suggestions and then it went down to 0.28 (wow! 2.03 --> 1.67 -->0.28) following your comments on `numexpr`. That is on a 8core pc running python 3.6, anaconda distribution without VML...(which I havent figured out how to make available). To all fairness, you deserve at least half the answer. Many thanks once again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exploit the sparseness of `x` using the `where` keyword.

```
def sprse(x, p):
    r = 2
    out = x * np.log(p, where=x.astype(bool)) + r * np.log(1-p)
    return out

from timeit import timeit
x = np.random.uniform(-13, 1, (3500, 90, 1)).clip(0, None)
p = np.random.random((3500, 90, 70))
assert np.all(sprse(x, p)==myFun(x, p))
def f():
    return myFun(x, p)
print(timeit(f, number=3))
def f():
    return sprse(x, p)
print(timeit(f, number=3))
```

Sample run:

```
5.171174691990018
3.2122434769989923
```

Comment: interesting one! Didnt cross my mind. I do see an improvement, around 15% better, not 40% as you do, for exactly the same piece of code as you posted above. Many thanks, quite neat approach

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following implementation. For this simple function this looks like a bit exaggerated, but I also had troubles to get `numexpr` to work with Intel SVML (otherwise I would prefer numexpr). This solution should give 0.07s per call on a Quadcore i7 and should scale quite well on more cores. Please also note that the first call has a compilation overhead of about 0.5s.

[Installing Intel SVML](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/performance-tips.html)

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

x = np.random.uniform(-13, 1, (3500, 90, 1)).clip(0, None)
p = np.random.random((3500, 90, 70))

@nb.njit(parallel=True,fastmath=True)
def nb_myFun_sp(x, p):
    out=np.empty(p.shape,p.dtype)
    r = 2.

    for i in nb.prange(p.shape[0]):
      for j in range(p.shape[1]):
        if x[i,j,0]!=0.:
          x_=x[i,j,0]
          for k in range(p.shape[2]):
            out[i,j,k] = x_ * np.log(p[i,j,k]) + r * np.log(1.-p[i,j,k])
        else:
          for k in range(p.shape[2]):
            out[i,j,k] = r * np.log(1.-p[i,j,k])

    return out

@nb.njit(parallel=True,fastmath=True)
def nb_myFun(x, p):
    out=np.empty(p.shape,p.dtype)
    r = 2.

    for i in nb.prange(p.shape[0]):
      for j in range(p.shape[1]):
        x_=x[i,j,0]
        for k in range(p.shape[2]):
          out[i,j,k] = x_ * np.log(p[i,j,k]) + r * np.log(1.-p[i,j,k])
    return out
```

Comment: Brilliant stuff! `nb_myFun` finishes almost in the same time as the `numexpr` implementation from earlier comments but the optimised `nb_myFun_sp` shaves another 10% off. A bit of overkill for this particular one but good case study. Thanks a million for all your comments! Really insightful